# Keyboard shortcut - Importing all missing modules in PyCharm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

I know that Eclipse allows me to do this. However, in PyCharm I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on every missing module to import it.

Is there a keyboard shortcut which allows me to import all missing modules at one go? Later, I could correct any incorrect imports.

Answer (score 3):

In Pycharm 2017, Alt + enter seems to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

As of PyCharm 4.0, there is no such shortcut.

Comment: Seems like a pretty simple/common/powerful thing that PyCharm is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Johan ist right, however your cursor has to be somewhere on the line of the missing artifact:

[image]

Alt+Eingabe here means Alt+Enter

Also see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Auto-import

In the end, for **ALL**: nope